# Iterate Object Deserialized JSON

Tags: json, vb.net, serialization, javascriptserializer

I cannot figure out how to iterate through an object to retrieve a list of errors sent in a JSON string.  I have a For Each loop looing at each key pair value in my JSON but the third key pair is an object of key pairs.  I cannot access these using the same For Each structure (I can access them if I loop through the object but want to keep it consistent if possible..  My 'Case Is "Errors" case statement is where I want to iterate the errors object but I am not sure how to get to it..  Here is my code..  I hope someone can assist..

Sample JSON:

> {"success":"true","api_reference":3821,"errors":[{"record":"landlord","record_id":"-16::1::LPMB40-2385DDDC","error":"Please
>   ensure the email field has been
>   completed","error_code":"33101"},{"record":"landlord","record_id":"-16::1::LPMB40-2385DDDC","error":"Please
>   ensure the email field is a valid email
>   address","error_code":"33102"}]}

```
                Dim jss = New JavaScriptSerializer()
            Dim data = jss.Deserialize(Of Object)(responseFromServer)
            Dim strSuccess = "", strAPIReference = ""
            Dim intExpiresIn = 0
            Dim ErrorsObject As Object

            For Each kvp As KeyValuePair(Of String, Object) In data

                Select Case kvp.Key

                    Case Is = "success"

                        strSuccess = kvp.Value

                    Case Is = "api_reference"

                        strAPIReference = kvp.Value

                    Case Is = "errors"

                        ErrorsObject = kvp.Value

                        For Each errorskvp As KeyValuePair(Of String, Object) In ErrorsObject


                        Next

                End Select

            Next
```

Comment: Please add example json.

Comment: Sorry, there you go..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest doing this strongly typed, so that you can deserialize the json to a real object and use the object properties. That way it's much easier to read the values and loop errors etc:

Classes:

```
Public Class JsonResponse
    Public Property Success As Boolean
    Public Property Api_reference As String

    Public Property Errors As IEnumerable(Of JsonError)
End Class

Public Class JsonError
    Public Property Record As String
    Public Property Record_Id As String
    Public Property [Error] As String
    Public Property Error_Code As String
End Class
```

Deserialization and use:

```
Dim j As New JavaScriptSerializer()

Dim data As JsonResponse = j.Deserialize(Of JsonResponse)(responseFromServer)

If Not data.Success Then
    For Each myError As JsonError In data.Errors

    Next
End If
```